# Mysterious error in CustomControl (dis)appearing.in VS 2017

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2017

I suddenly get the following error message in Visual Studio 2017 (version 15.7.3)  Error List window, when working on a XAML file:

```
#FFFFFFFF' is not a valid value for the 'Mocks.CoCa_Views_CustomControls_InputParameter_2_488624100.LBForeground
```

First, I have no idea where that "Mocks" comes from. A search through my Solution gives me nothing. 
Second: The error in the error list only shows when the XAML file is open in VS. If I close it, the error disappears.
Third: In the XAML file I use a CustomControl named InputParameter twice. Only the first use of the that CustomControl gives me the error. Not the second or later one.

I say: the first one only. If I comment the first one  out, then the second one  gets under-squiggled. I have another XAML file where the same thing happens.
Mind you: the compiling goes well, the program works, text is white in the right places etc.

#FFFFFFFF is the color number for white. LBForeground is the dep-prop for the text color in the CustomControl.

As I have the feeling there is nothing wrong with the code, I do not post the code (yet).
Has anyone ever seen this behaviour? Can you tell me about it?
What is Mocks?

Comment: `Mocks` *looks* like a namespace. As to your actual issue I have never encountered something like that before

Answer (score 0):

Has to do with mistaking a Colors number with a Brush type in a DependencyProperty.
The DepProp looks like this now:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TBBackgroundProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("TBBackground", typeof(SolidColorBrush), typeof(InputParameter),
          new PropertyMetadata(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White)));
    public Brush TBBackground
    {
        get
        {
            return (Brush)GetValue(TBBackgroundProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(TBBackgroundProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

In XAML the TBBackground prop must be set with a staticresource (being a SolidColorBrush)

The first typeof() cannot be a string like this:

```
 WRONGWRONGWRONG:
  public static readonly DependencyProperty TBBackgroundProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("TBBackground", typeof(string), typeof(InputParameter),
          new PropertyMetadata("Black"));
    public string TBBackground
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(TBBackgroundProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(TBBackgroundProperty, value);
        }
    }
```